# Android ListView not showing database result

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I have 2 android sqlite databases and I'm trying to see them both in the same listview, but just one of them it is shown.

This is my MainActivity where the listview it is shown.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.tubapps.accountdb.MESSAGE";

    private ListView obj, obj1;
    DBHelper mydb;
    DBHelperExpense mydb1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllIncomes();
        mydb1 = new DBHelperExpense(this);
        ArrayList array_list1 = mydb1.getAllExpenses();

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter1 =
                new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list1);

        //adding it to the list view.
        obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        obj1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

        obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.IncomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
                obj1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                            long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
                        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                        dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),tubapps.datepickerdb.ExpenseActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                        startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        Intent intent = null;

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.income_id:
                Bundle dataBundle_Income = new Bundle();
                dataBundle_Income.putInt("id", 0);
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),tubapps.datepickerdb.IncomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle_Income);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.expense_id:
                Bundle dataBundle_Expense = new Bundle();
                dataBundle_Expense.putInt("id", 0);
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),tubapps.datepickerdb.ExpenseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle_Expense);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }

}
```

This is my Income Database.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBIncome.db";
    public static final String INCOME_TABLE_NAME = "incomes";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER = "payer";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_PAYMENTS = "payments";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";


    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 8);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table incomes " +
                        "(id integer primary key, amount text, payer text, date text, payments text, category text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS incomes");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertIncome  (String amount, String payer, String date, String payments, String category)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("payer", payer);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        contentValues.put("payments", payments);
        contentValues.put("category", category);

        db.insert("incomes", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from incomes where id="+id+"", null );

        return res;
    }
    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, INCOME_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }
    public boolean updateIncome (Integer id, String amount, String payer, String date, String payments, String category)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("payer", payer);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        contentValues.put("payments", payments);
        contentValues.put("category", category);
        db.update("incomes", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }
    public Integer deleteIncome (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("incomes",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }
    public ArrayList getAllIncomes()
    {
        ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from incomes", null );
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

}
```

And this is my Expense DataBase.

```
public class DBHelperExpense extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBExpense.db";
    public static final String EXPENSE_TABLE_NAME = "expenses";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COLUMN_PAYEE = "payee";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COLUMN_PAYMENTS = "payments";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";


    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelperExpense(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 8);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table expenses " +
                        "(id integer primary key, amount text, payee text, date text," +
                        " payments text, category text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expenses");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertExpense  (String amount, String payee, String date, String payments, String category)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("payee", payee);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        contentValues.put("payments", payments);
        contentValues.put("category", category);

        db.insert("expenses", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from expenses where id="+id+"", null );

        return res;
    }
    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, EXPENSE_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }
    public boolean updateExpense (Integer id, String amount, String payee, String date, String payments, String category)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("payee", payee);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        contentValues.put("payments", payments);
        contentValues.put("category", category);
        db.update("expenses", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }
    public Integer deleteExpense (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("expenses",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }
    public ArrayList getAllExpenses()
    {
        ArrayList array_list1 = new ArrayList();
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from expenses", null );
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list1.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_PAYEE)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list1;
    }

}
```

When I try to save an income it doesn't show in the listview and it doesn't even have an error in the logcat.

This is the LogCat.

```
02-10 07:02:04.597    2264-2264/tubapps.datepickerdb W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-10 07:02:04.697    2264-2264/tubapps.datepickerdb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tubapps.datepickerdb/tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now I have this error. This is the LogCat.

```
02-10 07:10:54.328    2382-2382/tubapps.datepickerdb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tubapps.datepickerdb/tubapps.datepickerdb.ExpenseActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at tubapps.datepickerdb.ExpenseActivity.onCreate(ExpenseActivity.java:76)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is the Expense Activity.

```
public class ExpenseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
    private DBHelperExpense mydb;
    TextView payee;
    TextView expense_amount;
    Spinner payments_expense;
    Spinner expense_category;
    int id_To_Update = 0;

    private Calendar calendar;
    private TextView dateView;
    private int year, month, day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense);

        payee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_payee);
        expense_amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_expense);
        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_date);

        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_date);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDate(year, month+1, day);

        payments_expense = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.expenseNumber);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> payments_expense_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.recurring_expense, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        payments_expense_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        payments_expense.setAdapter(payments_expense_adapter);

        expense_category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.expenseCategory);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> category_expense_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.category_expense, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        category_expense_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        expense_category.setAdapter(category_expense_adapter);

        mydb = new DBHelperExpense(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                rs.moveToFirst();
                String amo = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelperExpense.EXPENSE_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
                String pye = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelperExpense.EXPENSE_COLUMN_PAYEE));
                String dat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelperExpense.EXPENSE_COLUMN_DATE));
                String pym = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelperExpense.EXPENSE_COLUMN_PAYMENTS));
                String cat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelperExpense.EXPENSE_COLUMN_CATEGORY));
                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnc);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                expense_amount.setText(amo);
                expense_amount.setFocusable(false);
                expense_amount.setClickable(false);

                payee.setText(pye);
                payee.setFocusable(false);
                payee.setClickable(false);

                dateView.setText(dat);
                dateView.setFocusable(false);
                dateView.setClickable(false);

                payments_expense.setSelection(getIndex(payments_expense, pym));
                payments_expense.setFocusable(false);
                payments_expense.setClickable(false);

                expense_category.setSelection(getIndex(expense_category, cat));
                expense_category.setFocusable(false);
                expense_category.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_expense, menu);
            } else {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Edit_Expense:
                Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnc);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                expense_amount.setEnabled(true);
                expense_amount.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                expense_amount.setClickable(true);

                payee.setEnabled(true);
                payee.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                payee.setClickable(true);

                dateView.setEnabled(true);
                dateView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                dateView.setClickable(true);

                payments_expense.setEnabled(true);
                payments_expense.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                payments_expense.setClickable(true);

                expense_category.setEnabled(true);
                expense_category.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                expense_category.setClickable(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.Delete_Expense:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteIncome)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mydb.deleteExpense(id_To_Update);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog d = builder.create();
                d.setTitle("Are you sure");
                d.show();

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void run(View view) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                if (mydb.updateExpense(id_To_Update, expense_amount.getText().toString(), payee.getText().toString()
                        , dateView.getText().toString(), payments_expense.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        expense_category.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (mydb.insertExpense(expense_amount.getText().toString(), payee.getText().toString()
                        , dateView.getText().toString(), payments_expense.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        expense_category.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                } else {
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setDate(View view) {
        showDialog(999);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // arg1 = year
            // arg2 = month
            // arg3 = day
            showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
        }
    };

    private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                .append(month).append("/").append(year));
    }
    private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString){

        int index = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)){
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }


}
```

Comment: Too much code, i'm sorry, tried to help you. In a polite way, i invite you to learn more about Android, or Java, or object-oriented programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two adapters and two ArrayLists, you may use only one of each. The database code appears to work, yet not the best approach using generic classes.

EDIT:

Try to change this:

```
mydb = new DBHelper(this);
ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllIncomes();
mydb1 = new DBHelperExpense(this);
ArrayList array_list1 = mydb1.getAllExpenses();

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list1);
```

with that:

```
mydb = new DBHelper(this);
mydb1 = new DBHelperExpense(this);
ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllIncomes();
array_list.addAll(mydb1.getAllExpenses());       

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You say i should use an ArrayList and an Adapter in the main activity ?

Comment: Yes, i said that. Put elements returned both from getAllIncomes() and getAllExpenses() in the same ArrayList, and define an adapter that can manage both types of object. Then, let listview use that adapter.

Comment: One listView must use only one adapter. You are setting two, so the second one pushes out the first.

Comment: I kind of understand what you say but I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: I just posted the LogCat

Comment: You are getting a null pointer exception in your onCreate method, but i don't know in what line (in your code, it's line 57, but in your pasted code, can't determine that). I suspect that the method getAllIncomes() is returning null. Try debugging it.

Comment: I managed to find that error. It saves both of incomes and expenses in the same listview but if I try to edit an expense it crashes the app.